# How to group several notifications into one on an android device client?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework, android-notifications

I own an application (Ionic for front-end and Java backend **involving GCM-Server library** ( REST) version 1.0.2).

In my application, I have a Chat where several users can talk to each other.
Each message involves a push notification from GCM to user.

User complains about the fact that too many Chat notifications are received on their Android device in a very short time.

Is there an easy way to group every Chat notifications into one on the client?
Meaning always displaying the latest by overriding previous one.

I thought about setting the same `notificationId` for all messages providing from the same Chat room.

What is a good practice to handle this case using gcm-server library?

Comment: I think I found the trick :  From here:  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref Tag property: "Indicates whether each notification message results in a new entry on the notification center on Android. If not set, each request creates a new notification. If set, and a notification with the same tag is already being shown, the new notification replaces the existing one in notification center."

Comment: Sounds to not work with the `tag` property set. It keeps stacking old notifications.

Comment: the tag field is intended to be used with Notification Messages, not data messages. What type of messages are you sending?

Comment: I sent a message with BOTH entries:   notification payload and message payload. And `tag` is associated to notification payload.

Comment: When you do that the new notification is not replacing the previous one with the same tag?

Comment: Exactly, I expect it to replace the old one..but it doesn't. That's the main point of my 2 OPs.

Comment: Could you confirm that you are not generating notifications on the Android side using the Android Notifications APIs?

Comment: I have a Ionic application (Javascript so), and a backend in Scala. This backend is connected to GCM.  So notifications are generated in the backend using this library: https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server.  I don't use at all the Android Notifications APIs so, since GCM enables a REST api with `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.

Comment: Could you add your http request and receiver code to the question?